# Enterprise 0x.org API access

Tags: 0x

We are currently using 0x API for data analysis, but we are getting blocked by the rate limiter many times.
I tried to search for 0x Enterprise API Access but couldn't find anything...
Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: sorry but can you say for examples some of the information that you want to collect? If it relate to blockchain like transaction then maybe you can code your own using web3

Comment: hi jake can you share more about what do you need the higher rate limit for? Is that for Ethereum or Polygon/BSC?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited] I think what you're looking for is this 0x API Taker Integration Request form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdUevfVTDbqnr2z7jBbuS-wMLu0wW9aHL0WZYb5B30TWFynhg/viewform

Comment: We are using your web API and noticed you have a pretty strict rate limiting (4 requests per second). We are mainly using the orderbook endpoint.
We are interested in paying for a higher rate.
Can you please provide us with pricing?

Comment: Ah, sorry I realized I posted the wrong link above (updated the comment). This is the one for 0x Taker Integration Requests: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdUevfVTDbqnr2z7jBbuS-wMLu0wW9aHL0WZYb5B30TWFynhg/viewform
If you could fill that out, our team will review and reach out about how we can help (e.g. setting up higher rate limits).

Comment: I don't have permissions to see/fill the above form

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited the permissions, it should work now